# Exception in thread "main" NumberFormatException

Tags: java

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1001"

I dont understand why this code throws exception.

`1001   elma    87` --> This is the text file and I'm sure this is a number.

```
public class Food {
    public String[][] foodArray = new String[1000][100];
    public int sayac = 0;

    public void readText() {
      try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("food.txt")))) {
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String bilgiler = sc.nextLine().trim();
            foodArray[sayac] = bilgiler.split("\t");
            System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(foodArray[sayac][0]));
            sayac++;
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1001"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at Food.readText(Food.java:13)
at Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

Comment: What code? It really helps if you include that in your question. You can do that by editing the question.

Comment: I just added thanks.

Comment: Also, could you paste where you are initializing the array and sayac

Comment: Added. I'm calling this in the main method and getting this error.

Comment: The problem is 'Byte Order Mark' and I found the solution. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem that I can see that in the file the character that is separating the words is not a tab (\t) character, but maybe just spaces.  That's why it is not able to `split` the line correctly.  Can you show us what the exact stack trace is?

Answer (score 0):

Delimiting character is not tab(\t) which is why the line is not getting split in different parts and whole line is stored at 0th index of the array. And when you use parseInt it tries to parse the whole line which is `1001   elma    87`

I would suggest using `bilgiler.split(" ")` which will take care of single or multiple spaces used as delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

your file line separator might not be tabs, i advise you to print the split array and use  `bilgiler.split("\\s+");` to split all the spaces between words